# Does Ubuntu work with dual sim phones?

Tags: smartphone

I would like to know if Ubuntu works with dual sim phones, and what are the minimum requirements for installing Ubuntu in smartphones.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is not something you just install on your existing smartphone. It is at a point right now where Canonical is trying to get smartphone manufacturers to ship their phones with it.

They have a page where you can sign up to receive a notification when it is available.

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register